# ng-click event listener fired when sibling element is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

The `ng-click` directive's event on a `button` element is being registered even by it's sibling `input` element.

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <button class="button button-small button-icon icon ion-navicon" 
            ng-click="toggleLeft();$event.stopPropagation();"></button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
</div>
```

Clicking inside the anywhere inside the `input` element also fires the click-event.
How do i solve this?

Comment: I dont see this behavior. Maybe you need to specify your problem further (provide a detailed example including additional stylings)

Comment: @Rouby the problem occured because the elements where inside a label.

Comment: @Rouby It is the same. Marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an event listener to an element contained within a `<label>` fires the event everywhere inside that container.

[angularjs ng-click event of two sibling tag fired, instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079509/angularjs-ng-click-event-of-two-sibling-tag-fired-instead-of-one)

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
  <div class="item item-input">
    <button class="button button-small button-icon icon ion-navicon" 
            ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>
```